# What minimum reputations one should have to ensure reps of other users don't get reduced owing to one's account deletion?

Tags: support

How many least reps one should have to ensure the one's account deletion doesn't affect others on whom the one voted?

Comment: Realted: [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740/260388)

Comment: Can you help me to summarize here whatever written there? Lazy to read so much. @Pandya

Comment: If a user gets deleted, every single rep earned by other users by posting answers on deleted Users account will be removed. This is so frustrating tbh, Because I remember losing 300 rep ^^

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto No, that is not true.There is a threshold of votes the user has cast. The votes are preserved if the threshold is met. The threshold is a high number. If the count is high and it affects many users of the site, they will be reviewed unless there is a voting fraud or targeting voting. This threshold is kept secret.